# Making a workbook only able to be opened in the excel desktop app

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, office365, microsoft-excel-365

I am working on a project that requires all of the users on it to be on the desktop app for sheet security reasons. The sheet security can be bypassed by simply not having VBA run by opening the sheet in either teams or browser.

Although I have some roundabout alternatives to security, the issue with sheet access is that the unprotected cells of the sheet will be accessible by people who shouldn't be able to.

In a perfect world I would like to make it so the sheet simply can't be opened in browser or teams, but if need be I might make a later post about security options in case I can't find a way to make this work.

Comment: Locking cells like described on the following page will work also in online and mobile versions of excel: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-75481b72-db8a-4267-8c43-042a5f2cd93a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out if you go to File > Info > Browser View Options, you can select which sheets to be shown in browser(and teams) view. So by setting up a dummy sheet that tells the user to reopen in the desktop app, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be impossible to stop people from using teams, web version or another excel like program to open your sheet.

Given that you want this because you need to run your macro's, you can actually take advantage of this.

You need to setup a few things.

1. Create a new sheet in your workbook, and place a message in it that the sheet needs to be opened with the desktop app, and place a macro button on the sheet to gain access. After people open the sheet, they click it to run your macro, that will grant them access.
2. Hide all other sheets, and protect the workbook with a simple code.
3. Create a macro that unlocks the workbook, shows all other sheets, hide the welcome sheet, and protect the workbook again.
4. Place a new macro somewhere that puts the sheet back into protected state and manages any saving that you have to do.

What this accomplishes is that if someone opens the sheet in the web version of excel, they are simply locked out unless they would know the unlock code.

You have to be careful with people saving the file in unprotected state though, but it might be possible to have a check when the last save took place, and if that happens, protect the sheet and save again.

Comment: You can prevent the file from appearing on Teams by making a policy to not posting it on Teams. You could even just block Excel documents but I suspect a policy will be enough

Comment: While true, that would block every excel sheet. My solution will work for just this excel sheet, but keep other excelsheets to work normally.